# How to have multiple file get contents in a loop?

Tags: php

How to have multiple file get contents in a loop like below?
I can not make the `url -> $url1` or `$url2`

```
$url1="";
$url2="";


for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {


$html= file_get_contents(${'url'}.$x);
```

Comment: @newboyhun can you suggest me your approach ?

Answer (score 3):

This would be much better suited to using an array of urls instead of individual variables. Example :

```
$urls = array(
    'http://www.example.com',
    'http://www.anotherexample.com'
);

$results = array();

foreach($urls as $index => $url)
{
    $results[] = file_get_contents($url);
}
```